# Outputting JS function output to a text area

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get this function to output to the textarea below. The current code below works, but it takes over the whole page rather than outputting to a text field. I am aware that the two are not properly hooked up. I have hacked around with this for quite some time and it is driving me insane now so this is the last stable version of this script.

Any advice?

```
  function doStuff()
  {
    var clkUrl = document.getElementById("clkUrl");
    var clkName = clkUrl.value;
    var assetUrl = document.getElementById("banUrl");
    var assetName = assetUrl.value;
    var impUrl = document.getElementById("impPix");
    var impName = impUrl.value;


    document.write('&lt;a href="'+clkName+'" target="_blank"&gt;'+'<br>');
    document.write('&lt;img src="'+assetName+'"&gt;'+'<br>');
    document.write('&lt;/a&gt;'+'<br>');
    document.write('&lt;img src="'+impName+'"&gt;'+'<br>');
  }

<input name="maininput" id="clkUrl" type="text" placeholder="Click Tracker" autofocus>
<br>
<input id="banUrl" type="text" placeholder="Asset URL">
<br>
<input id="impPix" type="text" placeholder="Impressions Pixel">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Get iFrame" onClick="doStuff()">
<br><br>
<textarea id="iframeoutput" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Two pieces of advice: 1. use jQuery. 2. try jsfiddle.com (and add a link here).

Comment: Trying to learn JS prior to jumping into jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `innerHTML` property of the `<textarea>`. Unlike normal `<input>`s, `<textareas>` don't have a value property, they render the contents between the start and end tag.

So the `doStuff()` function becomes:

```
  function doStuff() {
      var clkUrl = document.getElementById("clkUrl");
      var clkName = clkUrl.value;
      var assetUrl = document.getElementById("banUrl");
      var assetName = assetUrl.value;
      var impUrl = document.getElementById("impPix");
      var impName = impUrl.value;

      var output = document.getElementById("iframeoutput");
      output.innerHTML = '&lt;a href="' + clkName + '" target="_blank"&gt;' + '<br>';
      output.innerHTML += '&lt;img src="' + assetName + '"&gt;' + '<br>';
      output.innerHTML += '&lt;/a&gt;' + '<br>';
      output.innerHTML += '&lt;img src="' + impName + '"&gt;' + '<br>';
  }
```

See this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/po98uktu/).

Comment: Also, it is better to stack variables when declared at once, not using the var every time. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40grtsgm/1/) if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: @user3127242, this is purely a stylistic preference. There is no performance benefit to stacking them together, see [this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/testing-js-variable-declaration-speed) for proof. What can be helpful is grouping all the variables at the start of the function due to Javascript's [hoisting](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes) behaviour.